# Keeping user in the database between tests using Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, rspec-rails

My issue is that I have to create a new user and login for each individual capybara test.

An example is below:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "users" do
  describe "user registration" do
    it "should create a new user and log in" do
      # Register a new user to be used during the testing process
      visit signup_path
      fill_in 'Email', with: 'testuser'
      fill_in 'Password', with: 'testpass'
      fill_in 'Password confirmation', with: 'testpass'
      click_button 'Create User'
      current_path.should == root_path
      page.should have_content 'Thank you for signing up!'
    end
  end

  describe "user login" do
    it "should log in" do

      # log in
      visit login_path
      fill_in 'Email', with: 'testuser'
      fill_in 'Password', with: 'testpass'
      click_button 'Log In'
      current_path.should == root_path
      page.should have_content 'Logged in!'
    end
  end
end
```

The login test fails because the user no longer exists in the database for that test.

This could be fixed simply by putting both in one test, but I believe that is bad practice.

Also I have another file which currently is registering and logging in between each test using a before_do, which also seems to be quite bad... you [can see that code here](https://github.com/emesto/flashcards/blob/master/spec/features/flashcards_spec.rb).

For the record this is my first rails app so perhaps I am trying to do this the wrong way. I would like to dry it up as much as possible..

Is capybara really this bad to use on pages that require user login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it this way.

```
require "spec_helper"

  describe "Users" do
     subject { page }
     describe "User Registration" do
        before { visit signup_path }

        let(:submit) { "Sign up" }

        describe "with invalid information" do
           it "should not create a user" do
             expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
           end
        end

        describe "with valid information" do
           before do
             fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
             fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar12"
             fill_in "Password confirmation", with: "foobar12"
           end

           it "should create a user" do
              expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
           end

           describe "after registration" do
             before { click_button submit }
             it { should have_content 'Thank you for signing up!' }
           end

           describe "after registration signout and login" do
              let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }
              before do
                click_button submit 
                visit signout_path
                sign_in user     # sign_in is a method which u can define in your spec/support/utilities.rb . Define once and use at multiple places.
              end
              it { should have_content 'Logged In!' }
              it { should have_link('Logout') }
           end
        end
     end    
   end
```

# spec/support/utilities.rb

```
def sign_in(user)
  visit sign_path
  fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Log in" 
end
```

your every `describe` and `it` block will run after the `before` block in parent that's why we need to click_button in every block in above test cases.